# MySQL SELECT then UPDATE - repeat

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

```
SET @newTIME = '';
SELECT @newTime := `Timestamp` FROM `myTable`;
UPDATE `myTable` SET `Datetime` = from_unixtime(@newTIME)
```

I want to update the Datetime column with the Timestamp column data that has the from_unixtime() function applied to it. The above code only sets the last Timestamp to all of the Datetime columns. It seems the SELECT statement runs through all the table first and then the UPDATE statement runs.

One solution I thought would work is to use FOR UPDATE on the select statement:

```
SELECT @newTime := `Timestamp` FROM `myTable` FOR UPDATE;
```

but the "FOR" key word is not found in my version of MySQL apparently.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try: `UPDATE myTable SET Datetime = from_unixtime(Timestamp)`

Comment: because you don't have a condition in __UPDATE__, so the query run through all rows. try `UPDATE myTable SET Datetime = from_unixtime(@newTIME) WHERE condition`

Comment: 'With no WHERE clause, all rows are updated.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: There's only one datetime column, right? Perhaps you're confusing rows and columns

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos Betsos, works perfectly!